# How to cd to a directory with a name containing spaces in bash?

Tags: terminal

I tried `cd "~/Library/Application Support/"
-bash: cd: ~/Library/Application Support/: No such file or directory`

also `cd ~/Library/Application Support/
-bash: cd: ~/Library/Application Support/: No such file or directory`

Comment: Use `\ ` -> for directory name: `test one` -> you should write `cd test\ one`

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key after pressing the first few characters (this will then "fill in" the rest of the folder for you e.g. type `cd ~/L`<kbd>Tab</kbd> fills in `cd ~/Library/` then type `Ap`<kbd>Tab</kbd> and it will fill in the rest for you.

If there is a space between words and you don't want to use the methods above, put a `\` (backslash) before the space, e.g. `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support`.

Comment: Is the path case sensitive or insensitive? I can access Library by cd ~/library, but the tab method won't work if i got case wrong.

Comment: @colinfang OS X is case insensitive, but case-preserving. The bash shell must be a bit more discriminating when it comes to autocomplete.

Comment: @NReilingh - Aha, thx.

Comment: @colinfang: You can use `shopt -s nocaseglob` and `bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'` to make *bash* less sensitive to case.

Comment: colinfang - For a case insensitive tab completion with bash compatibility try 'zsh'. Also the wildcard completion of this shell is very good.

Answer (score 34):

The core issue here is how the shell (*bash*) does quoting and how that affects tilde expansion and splitting into “words” (arguments for the program being run).

*bash* only treats the leading tilde specially if it is not quoted. In addition, the following slash must also not be quoted.

At the same time, *bash* parses command lines into “words” based on non-quoted whitespace. The `cd` command typically requires exactly one argument (the destination directory). A command line like `cd foo bar` means to run `cd` with two arguments: `foo` and `bar`. If you only wanted to send a single `foo bar` argument, then you need to quote the space:
(e.g.) `cd foo\ bar` (see more quoting example below).

In your particular situation, you need to leave the tilde and the following slash unquoted while quoting the space in the directory name. Your `cd "~/Library/Application Support/"` trial ends up quoting too much (the tilde and its slash), while your `cd ~/Library/Application Support/` trial quotes too little (it omits quoting the space in the directory name).

The most common solution is to use single-character escaping to quote just the space:

```
    cd ~/Library/Application\ Support
```

You can also use single or double quotes around either just the space or the space and some other bits of that argument (but not the `~/`!):

```
    cd ~/Library/Application' 'Support
    cd ~/Library/Application" "Support
    cd ~/Library/App'lication 'Support
    cd ~/Library/Application" Supp"ort
    cd ~/'Library/Application 'Support
    cd ~/"Library/Application "Support
```

These kinds of quotes have different meanings, but they are identical in these examples. Single quotes protect literal strings while double quotes allow various expansions and substitutions in the quoted region.

Often, you can just let the shell do the work for you.

- Globbing (wildcards):

  ```
  cd ~/L*/Ap*
  ```

  You can use `shopt -s nocaseglob` to make globbing case insensitive:

  ```
  cd ~/l*/ap*
  ```
- Completion:

  Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> after entering `cd ~/L` will probably expand it to `cd ~/Library/`.
  Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> again after entering `Ap` (you now have `cd ~/Library/Ap`) will probably expand it to `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/` (the shell automatically inserted the escaping backslash).

  You can use `bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'` to make completion case insensitive:

  `cd ~/l` <kbd>Tab</kbd> → `cd ~/Library/`; `ap` <kbd>Tab</kbd> → `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/`

Comment: nice answer @Chris.  How did you get the Tab characters to look like keys?

Comment: @RobZ: It is the `<kbd></kbd>` HTML tag (one of several [HTML tags supported in SE markdown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user)).

Answer (score 14):

When you double-quote a path, you're stopping the tilde expansion. So there are a few ways to do this:

```
cd ~/"My Code"
cd ~/'My Code'
```

The tilde is not quoted here, so tilde expansion will still be run.

```
cd "$HOME/My Code"
```

You can expand environment variables inside double-quoted strings; this is basically what the tilde expansion is doing

```
cd ~/My\ Code
```

You can also escape special characters (such as space) with a backslash.

Answer (score 9):

You can alternatively just drag a folder to the Terminal window too, the complete file/folder path will be auto-pasted on drag.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the space in "`Application Support`"

Try `$ cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for spaced folders/files by
If the file or folder name contains
1)file name.extension 
the command should be
cd ~/file\ name.extension/ (or) cd ~/"file name.extension"/

Comment: How does this answer differ or improve upon any of the other, similar, answers?

Comment: Its the perfect terminal syntax for defining space and giving quotes is one of the user defined one and also using tab key does not take the name like 1)filename.ext 2)file name.ext While pressing tab for this type of name the auto completion of words are display upto "file" at that time we can use this backslash to define the space in terminal. @fsp

Comment: All of that info should be in the Answer to show readers how it's different from the 9 other Answers, including the accepted Answer.

Answer (score -1):

If the normal ways don't work, trying substituting spaces with `%20`.

This worked for me when dealing with SSH and other domain-style commands like `auto_smb`.