# Is it possible to have bash escape spaces in pwd?

Tags: macos, bash, iterm

I'd like to copy the current directory to the clipboard, something like: `pwd | pbcopy`. However, `pwd` does not escape the space, so something in "Application Support", for example, doesn't copy correctly. I don't seem to remember this always being the case, so I could have boffed something. Using iTerm2.

Is there bash setting to escape everything? having trouble searching, too many questions/topics about Spaces.app or <kbd>esc</kbd>.

Current:

```
$ pwd
/Library/Application Support/Google Earth/
```

Preferred:

```
$ pwd
/Library/Application\ Support/Google\ Earth/
```

Already seen posts: [Copying the current directory's path to the clipboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47216/copying-the-current-directorys-path-to-the-clipboard/47218#47218) and [How to cd to a directory with a name containing spaces in bash?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/how-to-cd-to-a-directory-with-a-name-containing-spaces-in-bash), which do not address this. I would have made a comment in the former, but I don't have the privileges.

Comment: I doubt it the copy is correct - what you want is the paste to deal with spaces - which app are you pasting in?

Comment: Great question. You'll soon have rep enough to comment. Welcome to the site!

Comment: `pwd | pbcopy` works fine for me in Terminal. Finder/Edit/Show Clipboard confirms it's ok.

Comment: @lhf Yes, should have checked in Terminal, which works as you stated. No luck in iTerm2, though. Maybe I should switch back...

Comment: How can this depend on the terminal emulator you're running? I've just tested and `pwd | pbcopy` works fine in iTerm2.

Comment: @lhf yes, piping to copy, it works. I failed to explain the crux of the problem: `cd \`pbpaste\`` gives me an unescaped space, and hence, `cd` doesn't recognize the directory. And, you're right, it doesn't matter the terminal emulator. I don't know what I was thinking earlier, because it doesn't work any better in Terminal. Must not have had a space.

Comment: Grenwar, see [my answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52492/21703) below. In short, just add double-quotes: `cd "\`pbpaste\`"`

Comment: Using single-quotes for string literals seems like the best solution, I don't understand why `echo \'$(pbpaste)\'` wouldn't work.

Comment: Ok, I have a better question, what is your reason for using `pwd |pbcopy`? I am about 98% sure there is a better solution.

Comment: your question name and the question are not same,
I answered question "Is it possible to have bash escape spaces in pwd?"
please, either edit question or its name.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This command will escape spaces properly:

```
printf "%q\n" "$(pwd)" | pbcopy
```

You can alias it using something with history like `cwd` if you don't mind re-defining a [different cwd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349105/bash-script-set-current-working-directory-to-the-directory-of-the-script)

```
alias cwd='printf "%q\n" "$(pwd)" | pbcopy'
```

Ditch the pipe to pbcopy if you want it to work more like pwd and just print out the escaped path.

---

Or, to print the pwd while also copying it to the clipboard, use `tee` and an output process substitution:

```sh
alias cwd='printf "%q\n" "$(pwd)" | tee >(pbcopy)'
```

Comment: does not work on mac

Comment: Works on my Mac.

Answer (score 5):

```
pwd | sed 's/ /\\ /g'
```

But I'm not sure this will ultimately fix your issue. pbcopy is copying exactly what it receives on stdin.

Comment: That will only escape spaces, which is not nearly enough, even though that is what the OP used as an example.

Comment: but this works in most cases the proper one from glenn didn't work out on my mac, there is no output at all

Comment: You can also use it as alias when you declare a function: function escapePWD() { pwd | sed 's/ /\\ /g'; } and use this for alias: alias epwd='escapePWD'

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to make `pwd` output escaped file paths, as this is generally not useful.

It does not make sense for `pwd` or `pbcopy` to be adding backslashes to what is copied.  If you wanted to copy the path into a text file or web post, you would not want a backslash inserted into it.

Probably what you want to do is create as separate alias, like `qwd`, to print the quoted form of the current directory, or just escape the output of `pbpaste`, which is as easy as putting it in double-quotes:

```
bash-3.2$ pwd
/Users/user
bash-3.2$ cd test\ dir/untitled\ \"folder/
bash-3.2$ pwd
/Users/user/test dir/untitled "folder
bash-3.2$ pwd | pbcopy
bash-3.2$ echo "`pbpaste`"
/Users/user/test dir/untitled "folder
bash-3.2$ cd
bash-3.2$ pwd
/Users/user
bash-3.2$ cd `pbpaste`
bash: cd: /Users/user/test: No such file or directory
bash-3.2$ cd "`pbpaste`"
bash-3.2$ pwd
/Users/user/test dir/untitled "folder
```

***Note that it is not just spaces that need escaping.***  Forward and backward slashes, star, question mark, ampersand, semi-colon, and other characters need escaping, too.  Safest is just to use double-quotes as in the example, which will work even if the path includes double-quotes in it.

If you want to be perverse about it, you could make AppleScript quote the current directory for you:

```
bash-3.2$ alias qwd="osascript -e 'return quoted form of POSIX path of (POSIX file \"./\" as alias)'"
bash-3.2$ qwd
'/Users/user/test dir/untitled "folder'
```

Otherwise I mostly agree with Glenn, except, as above, I would alias the quoted form to `qwd` so as not to interfere with the normal `pwd`:

```
alias qwd='printf "%q\n" "$(pwd)"'
```